# How to connect two list together in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlite

I have these two list:

```
names = ["John", "Barack", "Elon"]
numbers = ["0342", "03478878", "0345"]
```

They are my clients, what I want is that the item "John", should be linked with its number, which is the 0 position item in the list, and so on, I also want to link the other names with there numbers respectively,so like when I export them later into a sqlite database the number "0342" should be below John, and so on with rest of names.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by linking them. Do you mean concatenate because then you could do, names[0]+numbers[0]

Comment: No, i don't want to concatenate them

Comment: I want to link them, in such a way that even if new numbers i have of my clients, i can easily add them in below there names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is to do this with dictionary.

```
dct = {name: number for name, number in zip(names, numbers)}
```

As @ Onyambu pointed out, this works also by

```
dct = dict(zip(names,numbers))
```

Read this list expression from right to left:
`zip()` pairs each ith element in the lists with each other.
they are assigned to `name` and `number` respectively for each pair
and then they are collected as `key: value` pairs into a dictionary `{}`
which is then assigned to `dct`.

You get the number for each name in such a way:

```
dct["John"] ## "0342"
```

```
for name in names:
    print(dct[name])
```

## If there are more entries for "John"

It there are more entries, the code above would overwrite previous John values.
In that case

```
def to_dict(l1, l2):
    dct = {}
    for key, val in zip(l1, l2):
        dct[key] = dct.get(key, []) + [vak]
    return dict
```

This ensures that all values for each name are collected in lists.
`dct.get(key, [])` is a nice trick, because if looks whether the `key` is a key in `dct`, if not, this returns `[]` - so this guarantees in combination of list fusion `+ [number]` that at the end you have guaranteed a number or numbers in a list.

```
names = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "d"]
numbers = [1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5]

name2numbers = to_dict(names, numbers)

name2numbers["a"] ## [1, 4]
name2numbers["d"] ## [5]
```

## To search from value to name, just flip the lists in the function

```
number2names = to_dict(numbers, names)


number2names[4] ## ["b", "a"]
number2names[2] ## ["c"]
```

Comment: Using your method, it wouldn't be  a problem even if i add more numbers to John,right?

Comment: @SahibzadaMuhammad hm ... more numbers would require to assign to hte key John a list of numbers.

Comment: And, there is a problem in your code i think, zip works for tuples, but i have a list, i want a solution with lists

Comment: @SahibzadaMuhammad The longer your lists become, the faster will be to take the dictionary solution.

Comment: whats the purpose of the for loop? `dict(zip(names,numbers))`

Comment: @Onyambu ah true, one could do it directly! Write a new answer then!

Answer (score 1):

To link them using tuples, use:

```
>>> list(zip(names, numbers))
[('John', '0342'), ('Barack', '03478878'), ('Elon', '0345')]
```

Using a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(zip(names, numbers))
{'John': '0342', 'Barack': '03478878', 'Elon': '0345'}
```

Comment: whats the purpose of the loop? `dict(zip(names,numbers))`

Comment: @Onyambu didn't know you could do that, thanks! I'm very used to using dict comprehensions, updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to do that:

```py
linked = {}
names = ["John", "Barack", "Elon"]
numbers = ["0342", "03478878", "0345"]

for x, name in enumerate(names):
    linked[name] = numbers[x]

print(linked)
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

Use an Array of Records, storing each client and their information as a class then storing the instances of those classes in an Array